# Share homestead vagrant box and laravel project on Git

Tags: php, git, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

On my local machine I have created using homestead vagrant box a laravel project. Now I have an Homestead folder that contains many files like Vagrantfile, Homestead.yaml configuration and as soon as. I have also another folder sibling of Homestead folder that contain the Laravel files project. My question is how to share on Git this folders in order to clone the repository from another machine and recreate automatically the same Vagrant machine and the laravel project? In both folders there are composer.json files.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to have a "frozen" in time vagrant box you would init homestead, let it do it's thing and them remove anything that's not mentioned in the vagrant file, then use that as a base for your repo. You can also fork homestead, run init and the use that as a base.

Homestead has an extra provisioning script, by convention named `after.sh` (see [this](https://gist.github.com/zot24/09f1c87c97f9d16b8d4d) for an example and [this](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/Vagrantfile#L38) to see when it's called), which could clone your project from a separate repo into a place of your choosing (consistent with the project root you set up in your homestead file).

My point is -- don't mix development environment setup with your project files.

All of the above could be done under assumption you would have all the prerequisite software installed on your machine (vagrant, homestead, git, etc). Otherwise (maybe homestead would do it for you) you might also right a custom setup script that would check those dependencies, attempt to install them and the `up` the homestead box based on your configuration (something like a pre-init to [`init.sh`](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/init.sh) :)). Or just put the instructions in the readme file (or link to [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead)).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. What I want to achieve is that each developer just pulling down from repositories can re create the same frozen vagrant box and the files projects. I could push the homestead folder and the project folder as two differents repositories?what do you think?And so pulling down the homestead folder and calling the init you can re-create the vagrant machine.